# Get the latest workflow run from GitHub Actions using the Octokit API

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions, octokit

I'm using the [Octokit API](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18) to request a specific workflow run. I can see in the [documentation](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#actions-get-workflow-run) that I can request a specific workflow run by providing a workflow run ID. However I would like to always request the **latest** workflow run. How do I achieve this if I don't know what the ID will be?

E.g. the value of `workflow-run-latest` here would always be changing.

```
octokit.actions.getWorkflowRun({
    owner: owner,
    repo: repo-name,
    run_id: workflow-run-latest,
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Also asked here: https://github.community/t/get-the-latest-workflow-run-from-github-actions-using-the-octokit-api/137908?u=courtneycb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the list API it looks to me like the latest is always the first in the list. So one option might be to request with `per_page` set to `1` so you only get the latest.

```js
octokit.actions.listWorkflowRunsForRepo({
  owner: owner,
  repo: repo-name,
  per_page: 1,
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Just posting my code snippet that solved my problem here in case it helps anyone in the future :)

```
var workflowRuns = octokit.actions.listWorkflowRuns({
    owner: owner,
    repo: 'repo-name',
    workflow_file_name: 'file-name.yaml',
    per_page: 1
});
```